# Unification of higher rank types on contravariant positions

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, type-theory, rank-n-types

Quick example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}                                

l :: (forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Int                         
l f = 3                                                    

l1 :: forall a. a -> a                                     
l1 x = x                                                   

l2 :: [Int] -> [Int]                                       
l2 x = x                                                   


k :: ((forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Int) -> Int                
k f = 3                                                    

k1 :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int                            
k1 x = 99                                                  

k2 :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int                              
k2 x = 1000 


m :: (((forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Int) -> Int) -> Int                                           
m f = 3                                                                                        

m1 :: ((forall a. a -> a) -> Int) -> Int                                                       
m1 x = 99                                                                                      

m2 :: (([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int) -> Int                                                         
m2 x = 1000
```

Here:

- `l l1` typechecks
- `l l2` does not typecheck
- `k k1` does not typecheck
- `k k2` typechecks
- `m m1` typechecks
- `m m2` does not typecheck

While I am totally okay with what happens in `l` and `m` I don't understand the `k` part. There is some kind of relation of being "more polymorphic", for instance `forall a. a -> a` is more polymoprhic than `forall b. [b] -> [b]` because one can just substitute `a/[b]`. **But why does this relation flip if the polymorphic types are on contravariant positions?**

As I see `k` expects "a machine that takes machine operating on any lists that produces Int". `k1` is "a machine that takes any endomorphism-machine that produces int". `k1` offers therefore much more than `k` wants, so why doesn't it fit its requirements? I feel there is some mistake in my reasoning, but I can't get it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `k` promises that, when called as `k f`, each call to `f` will have as an argument a function of type `(forall b. [b] -> [b])`.

If we choose `f = k1`, we pass something that wants as input a function of type `forall a. a->a`. This won't be satisfied when `k` calls `f = k1` with a less general function (of type `(forall b. [b] -> [b])`).

More concretely, consider this:

```
k :: ((forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Int) -> Int 
k f = f (\xs -> xs++xs)

k1 :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int                            
k1 x = x 10 + length (x "aaa")
```

Both type check. However, reducing `k k1` we get:

```
k k1 =
k1 (\xs -> xs++xs) =
(\xs -> xs++xs) 10 + length ((\xs -> xs++xs) "aaa") =
(10++10) + length ("aaa"++"aaa")
```

which is ill-typed, so `k k1` must be ill-typed as well.

Therefore, yes -- contravariant positions do reverse the order of subtyping (aka "being less general"). For `A -> B` to be more general than `A' -> B'`, we want the former to put fewer requirements on the input (`A` must be less general than `A'`) and to provide more guarantees on the output (`B` must be more general than `B'`).

Comment: Looks like [things are going to change](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0287-simplify-subsumption.rst). I'm not terribly happy about that.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm for one very happy with that. Subsumption fails to work nicely with dependent types, and `forall` floating and deep instantiation are ugly hacks which are incompatible with proper first-class implicit function types.